# In counting problems, what is the formal definition for 'unordered sampling" and "unreplaced sampling"?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*Homework problem:*

Eight committee members are meeting in a room that has twelve chairs. In how many ways can they sit in the chairs?

*My thoughts:*

(1) Objects are unreplaced (one person cannot simultaneously be in more than one position)
(2) Unordered sampling (Suppose we list the pairings of person (type A, |A| = 8) to chair (type B, |B|=12) using the notation . The implication based on context   is that  is equivalent to  so ordering does not matter).

*Questions:*
(1) How are the terms mentioned in the title of the post formally defined?
(2) Do we decide whether a counting problem depends on ordering based on context? I.e., contextually it makes sense that order does/does not matter given what we want to count?

Comment: Does "upright and alert" count as a different way to sit in a chair than "lazy and sprawling"? How about sitting cross-legged, or turning the chair around and leaning on the back?

Comment: What is your point?

Comment: Oh, nothing in particular. Just ranting about the vagueness of the "how many ways can they sit" wording.